# Save a list of all applications in the Applications folder to a text file

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a basic program to place the names of all my applications in the application folder On MacOSX in a specified Text file.This is what I wrote. However each time I run It does not write to the file at all. The file stays empty. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set writetoFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/3TB STORAGE/Downloads/00. All Installed Apps on Mac.rtf" as alias
    set appfolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/" as alias
    set info to every item of appfolder
    set names to []
    set n to 1
    repeat with apps in info
        set appname to name of apps
        set names to names & appname
        writeTextToFile(appname, writetoFile, false) of me
    end repeat
    return names
end tell

on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try

        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string

        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission

        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0

        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof

        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true

        -- Handle a write error
    on error

        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

Comment: Try writing to a `.txt` file instead. Change the file name  `00. All Installed Apps on Mac.rtf` to  `00. All Installed Apps on Mac.txt` and update the reference to it in line 2 of your code. Then change the line of code which currently reads as: `write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof` to `write theText & return to theOpenedFile starting at eof` (this will add a line break).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below did the trick. I had to call the write function outside the "tell finder" block. Moving it out and changing file to '.txt' worked. Thanks for the input on throwing in a line break. I wanted a list, with one app per line. This Worked.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set writetoFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/3TB STORAGE/Downloads/00. All Installed Apps on Hack.txt" as alias
    set appfolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/" as alias
    set info to every item of appfolder

    set names to []
    set n to 1

end tell

writeTextToFile("", writetoFile, true) of me

repeat with apps in info
    set appname to name of apps
    set names to names & appname
    set appname to (n as string) & "). " & appname
    -- return appname
    writeTextToFile(appname, writetoFile, false) of me
    set n to n + 1
end repeat


on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try

        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string

        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission

        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0

        -- Write the new content to the file
        -- write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        write theText & return to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true

        -- Handle a write error
    on error

        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try

        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

Comment: This reports incorrectly. it reports everything at the top level of the _Applications_ folder regardless of its type. For example; any subfolders which reside at the top level of the _Applications_ folders (e.g. _"Utilities"_) will be listed in the resultant `.txt` file. Any documents, or aliases, residing there will be listed too. Also, any applications in subfolders of the _Applications_ folder will not be listed in the resultant `.txt` file. The `.txt` file must be created before running the script otherwise it fails to run.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving this code a shot...

```
tell application "Finder" to set appNames to name of application files in entire contents of (path to applications folder)

set saveTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {", "}
set appNames to appNames as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveTID

writeToAFile(true, appNames)

on writeToAFile(trueOrFalse, theAppNames)
    set overwriteFile to trueOrFalse
    set theFile to (path to desktop as text) & "All Installed Apps on Mac.txt" --value can be changed
    set theFile to POSIX path of theFile
    set theText to paragraphs of theAppNames as string
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        if overwriteFile is true then
            set eof writeToFile to 0
        end if
        write theText to writeToFile starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        if overwriteFile is true then
            set eof writeToFile to 0
        end if
        write theText to writeToFile starting at eof
        close access theFile
    end try
end writeToAFile
```

---

**Special thanks to user @CJK For his suggestion on a quicker and more efficient way to grab the application names (Which has been implemented in the second line of my code)**

Comment: Nice update to handle all the primary application bundles that exist in the `/Application` hierarchical folder structure. +1 Also this update is what one would reasonably expect and not diving deep into each primary application bundle to get the name of app bundles within, as it's doubtful one would want that aggregate information however, if they do they can use the find command from the other answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your implementation here, but another way of retrieving the relevant files without the `repeat` loop would be: `tell application "Finder" to get the name of the application files in the entire contents of the (path to applications folder)`.  That is one line that can replace 10 of the lines at the start of your script, and I believe it's a lot more efficient too (say, if there were many hundreds of files to check).

Comment: @CJK  at first i tried `set theApps to (name of files of entire contents of folder (path to applications folder)) whose name extension is "app"` but that approach took way to long.  I must admit that your solution is quite impressive!!

Comment: It would also be much faster, and a better coding practice, to create _paragraphs of text_ from `appNames` and preform a single `write` to `writeToFile`, then _writing in a loop_ as presently coded. Just saying! ;) I'd' also probably do away with `global appNames` and set the _handler_ to take two _parameters_, the `boolean` and the `appNames` _list_ (or _paragraphs of text_ if processed before the _handler_).

Comment: Your last edit puts a piece of garbage `listutxt` at the beginning of the file and is a comma separated list on one line and not paragraphs of text with one app name on each line. Oh well, I give up and wish I actually had the time today to write my own answer. But kudos for trying to improve your answer.

Comment: The line of text which reads `set theText to paragraphs of theAppNames` should be changed to `set theText to paragraphs of theAppNames as string` to circumvent the `listutxt$¶` garbage which @user3439894 refers to. The code in it's current form generates a `.txt` file which will be misinterpreted by text editors such as Sublime Text and TextMate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I recommend to use `System Events` because the `Finder` is terribly slow when filtering with `whose`.

This is a simple solution which gathers all application names and concatenates the list via `text item delimiters`.

As the `write` command supports also POSIX paths there is no need to coerce the path to HFS or alias

```
set applicationFolder to path to applications folder
set destinationFile to "/Volumes/3TB STORAGE/Downloads/00. All Installed Apps on Mac.txt"

tell application "System Events"
    set applicationNames to name of files of applicationFolder whose name extension is "app"
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, linefeed}
set namesText to applicationNames as text
set text item delimiters to TID

try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access destinationFile with write permission
    write namesText to fileDescriptor
    close access fileDescriptor
on error e number n
    try
        close access file destinationFile
    end try
    display dialog "Error: " & e & " - number: " & n buttons {"Cancel"} default button "Cancel"
end try
```

Alternatively use the shell, it makes a deep search also in subfolders and bundles but it can take some time (> 30 secs) and it lists the full paths.

Replace

```
tell application "System Events"
    set applicationNames to name of files of applicationFolder whose name extension is "app"
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, linefeed}
set namesText to applicationNames as text
set text item delimiters to TID
```

with

```
set namesText to do shell script "find /Applications -name '*.app'"
```

Comment: The issue I see with this is, it does not get all the apps installed within the e.g `/Application` hierarchical folder structure. As an example, it doesn't list any of the apps in the Utilities folder, nor any apps in a folder setup but the install of some applications, or any apps in folders that have been setup by the user for organizational purposes.

Comment: To your update: As it is quite normal that a typical program application bundle can contain additional application bundle within that make up the working app as it shows in Finder for example, I do not believe the intent of the OP was to get a listing of all application bundles that exist within a parent application bundle as shown in Finder. For example, does one really care about the 200+ application bundles that are within the Xcode.app bundle, doubtful.

Comment: I posted this comment against the other answer, but it might be worth posting here too.  Whilst I _completely_ agree that _System Events_ is typically a better choice for file handling than is _Finder_, the latter does a very fast job in this instance: `tell application "Finder" to get the name of the application files in the entire contents of the (path to the applications folder)`.

Comment: Consider using the `-prune` option with bash's `find` command, otherwise you'll include any sub-applications which may reside in the main application package. Will be much faster too!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you've had such a trial trying to get this to work along with some contributions that, to me, make the process look a lot more complicated than it actually is.  If all you want is, as you stated, just a list of applications printed to a file, you can do it in ten lines of AppleScript:

```
    property filename : "00. All Installed Apps on Hack.txt"
    property directory : POSIX file "/Volumes/3TB STORAGE/Downloads/" as alias
    property appsfolder : POSIX file "/Applications/" as alias
    property text item delimiters : linefeed

    tell application "Finder"
        try
            make new file at directory with properties {name:filename}
        end try
        write (the displayed name of every application file ¬
            in the entire contents of the appsfolder as text) to ¬
            (the file named filename in the directory as alias)
    end tell
```

Comment: This is hands down the best answer so far! +1

Comment: Yes @user3439894 I agree - CJK's solution is definitely the most efficient way using pure AppleScript - good work!  However, a slightly more performant (and terse!) solution would be to utilize `find` in a shell script - as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379829/save-a-list-of-all-programs-in-the-applications-folder-to-a-specified-text-file#answer-52429529).

Answer (score 1):

### AppleScript solution:

Below is a performant and terse AppleScript solution:

```c
do shell script "{ find /Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/ -name '*.app' -prune | sed 's#.*/##; s/.[^.]*$//'; } | sort -f >/Volumes/3TB\\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\\ All\\ Installed\\ Apps\\ on\\ Hack.txt"
```

This solution utilizes a shell script which is executed via AppleScript's [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command.

### Bash solution:

Essentially, the AppleScript (above) executes the following Shell script:

```bash
{ find /Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/ -name '*.app' -prune | sed 's#.*/##; s/.[^.]*$//'; } | sort -f >/Volumes/3TB\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\ All\ Installed\ Apps\ on\ Hack.txt
```

This Bash command can be run in your *Terminal* application, (or other preferred command-line tool), and the resultant output will be the same as the aforementioned AppleScript.

---

### Explanation:

The following provides further explanation regarding each constituent part of the shell script:

1. The first part which reads;

   **`find /Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/ -name '*.app' -prune`**

   , utilizes the [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) command.

   - The first argument; `/Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/`, is the path to the *Application* directory. It informs `find` where to begin recursively descending the directory tree from.
   - The `-name '*.app'` option and argument returns only the pathnames whose last component matches `.app` (i.e. *application* files only).
   - The `-prune` option prevents `find` from descending further into the current file<sup>1</sup>.
2. The next part:

   **`| sed 's#.*/##; s/.[^.]*$//'`**

   , pipes each matching pathname, returned by the  `find` command, to [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). This extracts only the application name from the the pathname, i.e. the *basename* minus file extension part only.

   - The first expression `s#.*/##` removes the part before the last forward slash. For example:

     ```bash
     echo "/Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/Safari.app" | sed 's#.*/##'
     # prints: `Safari.app`
     ```
   - The second expression `s/.[^.]*$//` utilizes sed's [s command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) to extract only the Application name only. For example:

     ```bash
     echo "Safari.app" | sed 's/.[^.]*$//'
     # prints: `Safari`
     ```
3. The commands in the aforementioned points 1 and 2 are wrapped in curly braces; i.e. `{ ... ;}`. This groups the commands and ensures both the `find` and `sed` commands are executed in the current shell context, thus avoiding any subshell from being created.
4. The next part;

   **`| sort -f`**

   , pipes the list of all applications names to the [`sort`](https://ss64.com/osx/sort.html) command for sorting in alphabetical order.

   - The `-f` option helps determine sort order, it ensures lower case to upper case characters are treated equivalently.
5. The final part:

   **`>/Volumes/3TB\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\ All\ Installed\ Apps\ on\ Hack.txt`**

   essentially saves the list to a `.txt` file.

   - The `>` [redirects](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) the list of sorted application names (from *stdout*) to a new file, saving it at the given path location.<sup>2</sup>

---

### Note regarding specifying paths:

When providing paths for either; the location of the *Applications* folder, or the location of where the resultant text file is to be saved - you'll need to escape any space character(s) which may exist. For instance your path;

> `/Volumes/3TB STORAGE/Downloads/00. All Installed Apps on Mac.rtf`

, includes several spaces. These will need to be escaped with either two backslashes (`\\`) when specified in the Applescript `do shell script` command. For example:

```
/Volumes/3TB\\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\\ All\\ Installed\\ Apps\\ on\\ Mac.rtf
```

Or, escaped with a single backslash (`\`) when running the equivalent bash solution directly via your command-line (e.g. *Terminal* application). For example:

```
/Volumes/3TB\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\ All\ Installed\ Apps\ on\ Mac.rtf
```

---

### Numbering each application in the list:

I noticed that in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379829/applescript-write-to-file-does-not-write#answer-52398652) you are prefixing each listed application with; a number, followed by a closing parenthesis, and a dot. For example:

```
1). foo
2). baz
3). quux
...
```

To achieve this you can utilize the bash [`nl`](https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html) command and change the redirections to utilize a [here string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) (`<<<`). Below are the revised scripts which do that:

**Revised AppleScript:**

```c
do shell script "nl -w3 -s'). ' >/Volumes/3TB\\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\\ All\\ Installed\\ Apps\\ on\\ Hack.txt <<<\"$({ find /Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/ -name '*.app' -prune | sed 's#.*/##; s/.[^.]*$//'; } | sort -f )\""
```

**Revised Bash solution**

Essentially, the revised AppleScript (above) executes the following Shell script:

```bash
nl -w3 -s'). ' >/Volumes/3TB\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\ All\ Installed\ Apps\ on\ Hack.txt <<<"$({ find /Volumes/SierraM550/Applications/ -name '*.app' -prune | sed 's#.*/##; s/.[^.]*$//'; } | sort -f )"
```

You may need to change the `-w3` part to get the numbers to align correctly. If you've got less than one hundred applications change it to `-w2`. Or change it to `-w4` if you've got greater than a thousand applications.

---

**<sub>Footnotes:</sub>**

**1** <sub>When omitting the `-prune` option the resultant list of applications will be far greater. This is because any sub-application(s) within an application package will be found too. By omitting `-prune` you essentially include all the applications that you would find by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>'ing on an application in the *Finder* and choosing *"Show Package contents"*.</sub>

**<sup>2</sup>** <sub>If you want to append a new list to the existing `.txt` file each time the script is run, as per the solution provided in your own answer, then use the `>>` redirection operator instead of the single one (`>`). For example:</sub>

<sub>`>>/Volumes/3TB\ STORAGE/Downloads/00.\ All\ Installed\ Apps\ on\ Hack.txt`</sub>

---

Comment: Great answer and explanation, @RobC, which is what I’ve come to expect from you.